# How to take Android Developer Console Public Key and convert it to a PEM

Tags: php, android, openssl, bouncycastle

How do I take the Base64EncodedString provided in the developer console and make it into a .pem that can be used for `openssl_verify()`?

Answer (score 0):

Add the appropriate header and footer and break lines as described here: http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rsa.html

Test using OpenSSL commands.

Answer (score 0):

[phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net), will take public keys in just about any format and verify signatures with them.  eg.

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();  
$rsa->loadKey('publickey.txt'); 
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1); 
echo $rsa->verify( 
    file_get_contents('plaintext.txt'), 
    file_get_contents('signature.txt') 
) ? 'verified' : 'unverified';
```

Here's another stackoverflow question where the person was able to use phpseclib even without the appropriate headers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13015915/569976